# postgres - приоритизированные условия для группы

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть следующая таблица:

```
create table cafes (
  id uuid not null
    constraint cafes_pkey primary key,
  identity uuid not null,

  is_closed boolean,
  is_illegal boolean
)
```

И задача - выбрать по одному кафе из каждой группы (группировка осуществляется по `identity`), для которого:

- приоритет#1: `is_closed = true`
- приоритет#2: `is_illegal = true`

То есть, если имеем закрытое кафе - выбираем его. Если таковых нет - выбираем первое с `is_illegal = true`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как такое можно реализовать?)

Comment: Создайте fiddle - 3-4 группы по 2-4 кафе на группу. И покажите результат для этих данных.

Comment: Ответ дан в https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/260758/postgres-11-prioritized-where-clause-in-group/260766 . Всем спасибо!))